# How to use page query while using root-wrapper for providing Theme with Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, styled-components

I am using `wrapRootElement` function in gatsby for providing `ThemeProvider` of `styled-component` on the root element. Here is the code :

```
export const wrapRootElement = () => {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') return <span>Something went wrong!</span>
  return(
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
         <FadeTransitionRouter>
            <Page path="/" page={<IndexPage />} />
            <Page path="/plan" page={<PlanPage />} />
            <Page path="/promos/:slug" page={<Template />} />
        </FadeTransitionRouter>
      </ThemeProvider>
)};
```

Because of this I am compelled to use staticQuery in pages as page queries are not working there. But I need to use page queries to introduce variables in `graphql` queries. How can I achieve this ? If I do not use `wrapRootElement`, my page queries works fine. But it is important for me to use it as I need to provide my external Theme to all the pages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't wrapping the root element here, you're replacing the entirety of the Gatsby app tree. You're probably seeing warnings about page queries being ignored because they're in files that aren't being treated like pages, which is likely where the source of confusion is.

Here's the example the Gatsby docs provide:

```
exports.wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {element}
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Note how this example accepts an `element` prop that it passes down as the children to the `Provider` component? That's what you're missing. You probably want something like this:

```
export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) =>
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    {element}
  </ThemeProvider>
```

You don't need to check for the existence of `window` here. If you're in `gatsby-browser.js` it will only ever be executed in the context of the browser. If you're in `gatsby-ssr.js` it'll only ever be executed in the context of node. Either way, they need to produce the same DOM output in order to have React hydrate cleanly. Bailing in the way you've shown will result in your entire DOM being replaced when React hydrates, which is less efficient than a client-side rendered app.

Finally, I removed the `FadeTransitionRouter` bit because you haven't shared what that is and it is unlikely to be compatible with Gatsby routing. If you'd like to have page transitions, [this page in the documentation has details on how to set this up](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-page-transitions-with-plugin-transition-link/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I do the way you have told, how will I do routing ? Suppose I have 3 pages in pages/ folder. What should I write in the {element} place ? Sorry I am new to this so needed help here.

Comment: Gatsby handles routing for you. Check the documentation link I shared for an example of how to handle page transitions within the context of Gatsby.

Comment: @PraveshChoudhary Does this answer your question or do you still need help?